# RecyclerView seems pretty slow - Way to fix?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an application for tracking calories. I have a SQLite Database implemented with [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) and a RecyclerView in on of my Fragments which shows the saved food of the users.

I have problems with the performance of the list. With about 50 entries it takes at least one second in the emulator. On my mobile phone (Samsung Galaxy S5) it already takes several seconds. A list element doesn't show much information, so I wonder about the speed.

I have already read many entries on the Internet, but have not become smarter. I load the pictures with Glide, otherwise only 2 TextViews are shown.

I also wondered if the problem is `notifyDataSetChanged()`. An alternative would be [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil). I already implemented [AsyncListDiffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/AsyncListDiffer) but the RecyclerView is still pretty slow.

This is the important part of my Fragment:

```
if(!mAdapter.hasObservers()) mAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);

mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new FoodRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onItemClick(Food food) {
        DiaryEntriesAddDialog dialog = DiaryEntriesAddDialog.newInstance(food);
        dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), DiaryEntriesAddDialog.class.getName());
    }
});
mRecyclerViewFood.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mRecyclerViewFood.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
mRecyclerViewFood.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

mFoodViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FoodViewModel.class);
mFoodViewModel.getAll().observe(this, new Observer<List<Food>>() {
@Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Food> foods) {
        mFoods = foods;
        mAdapter.setItems(foods);
});
```

The function I update my list:

```
public void setItems(List<Food> foods) {
    mFoods = foods;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And this is the ViewHolder in my Adapter:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.recyclerview_foodlist_item_constraintlayout) ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.recyclerview_foodlist_item_name) TextView mTextViewName;
    @BindView(R.id.recyclerview_foodlist_item_unit) TextView mTextViewUnit;
    @BindView(R.id.recyclerview_foodlist_item_imageview_type) ImageView mImageViewType;

    @BindArray(R.array.array_dialog_foodadd_units) String[] mUnitNames;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public void bind(final int position) {
        final Food food = getItem(position);

        mTextViewName.setText(food.getName());
        mTextViewUnit.setText(mUnitNames[food.getUnit()]);
        Glide.with(mContext).load(getEntryTypeDrawableResource(food)).into(mImageViewType);
}
```

Does anyone have an explanation? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

**EDIT**
I did some further investigations. According to the Profiler [image: Profiler Snippet] the `LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk` is the most time consuming operation (in debug: ~2 sec) while loading/displaying the items. Each `onCreateViewHolder()` needs between 3 ms and 100 ms. Almost 100 items could then easily generate these 2 sec.
But why is it that long?

This is my `onCreateViewHolder()`

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    mContext = viewGroup.getContext();
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_foodlist_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

And this is the layout I am inflating

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id = "@+id/recyclerview_foodlist_item_constraintlayout"
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "56dp"
android:background = "?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable = "true"
android:focusable = "true"
android:foreground = "?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
>

<ImageView
    android:id = "@+id/recyclerview_foodlist_item_imageview_type"
    android:layout_width = "24dp"
    android:layout_height = "24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart = "16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop = "16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom = "16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_foodlist_item_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop = "16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd = "16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom = "16dp"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textAppearance = "@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf = "parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf = "@+id/recyclerview_foodlist_item_unit"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf = "@+id/recyclerview_foodlist_item_imageview_type"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_foodlist_item_unit"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop = "16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd = "16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom = "16dp"
    android:text="Unit"
    android:textAppearance = "@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: "With about 50 entries it takes at least one second in the emulator. On my mobile phone (Samsung Galaxy S5) it already takes several seconds" -- what is "it"? Did you use your IDE's profiler to determine where your time is being spent? Did you write instrumented tests (e.g., of your Room access), and if so, does that help you identify where your time is being spent?

Comment: @CommonsWare Good question! It's just the time I have to wait until the Recyclerview has finished. So no detailed measuring here at the moment. But it's terrible enough that I can easily feel the delay without measuring.
I load the data from my database with LiveData. That's why I ruled out the possibility it might be because of that. I thought LiveData is working on another thread. But I could be wrong?

Comment: "But it's terrible enough that I can easily feel the delay without measuring" -- the point of measuring is to determine where the delay is coming from. "I thought LiveData is working on another thread" -- yes, but that does not magically make its work run faster. If the work would take 17 centuries, then it will still take 17 centuries. It just will not block the main application thread for those 17 centuries. So, between log statements, IDE-based profiling, instrumented tests, etc., you should have enough tools to be able to identify the specific place where your problem lives.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah you are right. I didn't do any proper measuring. And of course, working on the main thread or another doesn't speed up the application. But if something is working on the main tread it stops the application and the user interaction within the app. That's what I noticed. I asked the question because I am pretty new to Android Development and maybe there are people who struggle with the same issue. I will test my application but meanwhile I would appreciate if someone has an idea of what I can improve for the lack of responsibility

Comment: "But if something is working on the main tread it stops the application and the user interaction within the app. That's what I noticed." -- enable `StrictMode` to report disk I/O on the main application thread, and see what it reports.

Comment: @CommonsWare I already tried that while we were talking. Unfortunately or fortunately I get nothing in my log according to Strict Mode. No errors or warnings.
I use `StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog().build());` and `StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog().penaltyDeath().build());` in the `onCreate()` of my MainActivity.
The only warning I get is `I/Choreographer: Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` which supports my suspicions

Comment: OK, so it's not database I/O. And, the "skipped 59 frames" means that you are tying up the main application thread for ~944ms (16ms per frame), which lines up with your observation that the UI was frozen. However, I see nothing in your code that suggests a spot where you might be tying up the main application thread to that degree. So, we're back to `Log` statements, method tracing, and similar approaches for you to identify where exactly the time is going.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated my post